# How to convert 'JpegImageFile' to string in order to send it via socket

Tags: python

I need To convert JpegImageFile to string in order to send it via TCP socket to a server but I am not sure how...

Here is my current code

```
my_socket = connect_to_server()

data = Image.open('a.jpg')
#Need to convert data to string
my_socket.send(data.encode())
my_socket.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to a `base64` string and send the image.

```
import base64
from io import BytesIO

buffer = BytesIO()
data.save(buffer, format="JPEG")
base64_img = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue())
```

Then,

```
my_socket.send(base64_img)
my_socket.close()
```

To read,

```
im = Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_img)))
```